# Unable to read Cookies from Browser

Tags: java, asp.net, tomcat, cookies

The following is the scenario:

**Portal 1**
We have intranet portal which is developed using ASP.NET and upon successful authentication a cookie(logged-in user) is created in the browser.

**Portal 2**
We have another portal(running on Apache tomcat) has to read the cookie(logged-in user) from the browser and display the welcome text

Initially the user access **portal 1** after successful authentication the user access **portal 2**(by overwriting URL in the browser) which should read cookie from the browser and display the successful text.
After the URL is overwritten in the browser with portal 2 we are unable to read the cookies.

Pls suggest possible solution.

Thanks
vijay

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you switch the domain, the browser won't allow the second domain to access any resource (including cookies) from the first domain.

You can work around this using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but what you probably want to do is use a single sign on solution. Because you have different platforms for each application, take a look at this post to get you started: [cross platform SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986156/cross-platform-sso-where-to-start).